# C++ - Initialisation of empty array of objects sending bad access error

Tags: c++, arrays, object, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create an array of a object Cell in `main` function,

```
int nc=26 730 899;
Cell c[nc];
```

and Cell is a object which I am constructing with no arguments in.

```
// Constructor
Cell::Cell(){};
```

when `nc` is relatively low it works fine. The problem is when it takes big numbers, like the one in example, where it compiles, but retrieves a bad access error.
Does it mean my computer has no further memory, what kind of memory is this and how can work around this issue?

I am trying to develop a program to run computational fluid dynamics problems using finite volumes method, where each cell is an object so I will need tones of cells!
In the example (3D) I am just trying 299 cells in x by 299 in y by 299  in `z = 26 730 899`, which is very short yet.

Maybe my approach is being performed the wrong way!?

I am completely new to c++, so keep it as simple as possible, pleaseee. :)

Thank you all.

Note:
I don't know if is it relevant, but I am running the code in Xcode on a MacBookPro from 2010.

Comment: That is a variable length array. It's not standard C++, but an extension. Among the reasons you shouldn't use it is that a large VLA will deplete the available stack memory in no-time. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to store large array on the stack and face stack overflow. You should allocate large arrays on the heap or utilize corresponding library container - `std::vector`.

Comment: Start with something simpler, like a hello world program. Then add complexity one step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean my computer has no further memory,

Your compiler, unless told otherwise, produces executable programs in which the total size of objects with what the C++ language calls *automatic storage duration* is limited in a way that makes sense for the operating system on which the program should run.

You haven't shown your full code, but your array apparently has automatic storage duration.

Now, C++ automatic storage duration is usually implemented with something called the *stack*. How that stack works, how it is limited and how you can change those limits for your program is all implementation-specific.

What matters here is that you just shouldn't create huge objects with automatic storage duration. It's not made for that purpose.

> and how can work around this issue?

Use dynamic storage duration and put the objects on the *free store* with `std::vector`:

```
int nc = 26730899;
std::vector<Cell> c(nc);
```

---

<sup>[*] Your code is also using a non-portable GCC extension, because in standard C++, an array's size must be fixed at compile time, but that doesn't matter much for the problem at hand; you'd probably get the same error if `nc` was `const`.</sup>